# Weird behaviour of #each for an array with zero

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I'm using meteor (1.2) and try to use {{#each}} to iterate an array.
The array is generated by a helper.
I use something like this (simplified for debug, of course)

```
{{numbers}}<br>
{{#each numbers}}
   {{this}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

And all is ok, unless I get an array like [100, 100, 100, 100, 0].
In this case I get this

```
100,100,100,100,0

100
0
100
100
100
```

It's not the order that I want to see.
Arrays without zeroes are shown without problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: No issue for me]

For me I don't have any issues with your code on Meteor 1.2.1.
You can use `@index` to get index of the current iteration and access the elements using a helper like this,

In your HTML,

```
{{numbers}}<br>
{{#each numbers}}
    {{@index}} - {{getNumber @index}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

In your JS,

```
getNumber: function (index) {
  return numbers[index];
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I'm using dictionary, but this is a crutch, not a solution.

Comment: > For me I don't have any issues with your code
-
The weirdest part that I use this template in several pages and for some of the all works without problems.

Comment: Since the template is working fine in some templates and not working as it should in others, it most probably is caused by Meteor. Check for other helpers that might have changed your array/dictionary that is causing the issue.

Comment: It's only one helper for this template and as I said {{numbers}} shows the correct array order, the problem only with #each. It looks like a rendering problem.

Comment: Seems like a genuine bug, since `{{numbers}}` is in the correct order and `each` is not printing in the same order. You might want to post the bug to https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues and mention all information like meteor version, OS version and other details, if you didn't do that already. You might be able to get help from meteor guys directly.